# How to generate user-defined warning messages in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pragma, preprocessor-directive

I would like to generate a user-defined warning message in VB.NET as is done in C# (see below):

[How to use the #pragma message to generate user-defined warning messages in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155196)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

Unfortunately this is not possible using VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

It is not done in C#, you refer to something in C++

However, you can use the attribute `<Obsolete("some comment")>` for classes, functions, and subs; and this does create a warning.

Here the code-version, so use Obsolete. Since you can add any text, you should be able to refine the purpose of the warning.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, obsolete seems to be the only way, and only applying to classes. cannot inherit from it, and according to google search, the only other way would be to write a visual studio plugin that adds warnings depending on some custom attributes. So not worth the work

Comment: This is however possible in C#. The article he mentions just happens to be referring to C++.